# Compute the integral $\int \frac{1}{-x + \alpha x^n + \frac{\alpha}{2} n (1-x) x^{n-1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $n \in \{2,3,\dots\}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ I wish to compute the following integral:
$$
\int \frac{1}{-x + \alpha x^n + \frac{\alpha}{2} n (1-x) x^{n-1}}dx.
$$
When computing it with Mathematica, I get no result for general $n$ and when I fix $n$ to be some specific value, I get nasty expressions like, [for example for $n=5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F(+-x+%2B+a*x%5E5+%2B+a%2F2+*+5+*+(1-x)+*+x%5E4)).

I was wondering if there is some trick to compute the integral for general $n$ as the integral does not look that complex.

This integral comes up in the context of a differential equation:

$x' = -x + \alpha x^n + \frac{\alpha}{2} n(1-x)x^{n-1},$

which I attempt to solve analytically. I have solved it numerically this is not a problem. For the analytical solution I have used WA to obtain an expression for this integral but the expression it gives is not something I can use to find a closed formula for $x$.

Comment: "as the integral does not look that complex" - it does look quite complicated for general $n$. The larger $n$ the more roots the polynomial in the denominator has. Which in general makes the expression for the integral more awkward. You might not be able to express it in radicals or in elementary functions at all. The expression that WA gives is a sum over all the roots of the polynomial, which it can't express in closed form, because the equation is of order $5$

Comment: "if there is some trick to compute the integral" - you can just evaluate it numerically. I don't see any other trick here

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source of the problem, its motivation, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. In particular, what is the motivation for this integral - why is its value of interest?

Comment: There are no shortcuts to the analytical expressions that WA gives. By the way, if you don't forget to substitute one $n$ for $5$, WA gives you a closed-form expression. It is also clear that for higher degrees there are no closed-forms at all.

Comment: I adjusted the link to WA. Thank you for the responses, sad to hear there are no shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha works here with the *expansion into partial fractions* (   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition , sections: “Application to symbolic integration” and "Procedure"), which is the standard method for such a problem (= Polynomial in the denominator) .

The solution for $\,n=2\,$ is $\,\displaystyle \frac{\ln x}{\alpha -1} + constant$ .

The solution for $\,n>2\,$ is:

$$ \int\frac{dx}{-x+ \alpha x^n+\frac{1}{2}\alpha n(1-x)x^{n-1}} =$$ $$= \frac{1}{n-2}\sum\limits_{\{\omega: (n-2) \alpha \omega^{n-1}-n\alpha \omega^{n-2}+2=0\}}\frac{-n\ln(x-\omega)+(n-2)\omega\ln(x-\omega)}{(n-1)\omega-n} -\ln x + constant$$

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the original question, but a remark about the ODE.

To me this looks like a job for perturbation methods. In case an approximate solution would be useful, and using the fact that $\alpha$ is small, we can formally write:

$$x(t)=x_0+ \alpha x_1+\alpha^2 x_2+\dots$$

And substitute this into the original equation:

$$x_0'+ \alpha x_1'+\alpha^2 x_2'+\dots = \\ = -\left(x_0+ \alpha x_1+\alpha^2 x_2+\dots \right) +  \alpha \left(x_0+ \alpha x_1+\alpha^2 x_2+\dots \right)^n + \\ +\alpha \frac{n}{2}\left(1-x_0- \alpha x_1-\alpha^2 x_2-\dots \right)\left(x_0+ \alpha x_1+\alpha^2 x_2+\dots \right)^{n-1}$$

Keeping only certain powers of $\alpha$ at each step, we obtain a sequence of ODEs:

$$x_0=C_1 e^{-t}$$

$$x_1'=-x_1+C_1^n e^{-nt}+C_1^{n-1} \frac{n}{2} \left(1-C_1 e^{-t} \right)e^{-(n-1)t}$$

And so on.

From the form of the equation we can guess that for large $t$ the asymptotic solution should approach $x=x_0=C_1 e^{-t}$.

---

For small $t$ one could use a Taylor series approximation instead of perturbations:

$$x(t)=a_0+a_1 t+a_2 t^2+\dots$$

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for this insightful response! I would upvote your answer but I can't as I do not have sufficient reputation.. I did not know of this method for solving ODEs but it's nice. It $x(t)=C_1e^{-t}$ is indeed the form of solution I would have expected!

Comment: My boundary condition is in fact $x(0) = \alpha$ which means $C_1 = \alpha$. I read (http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahhwi/LTCC/section2-3-perturb-regular.pdf) that you should use this boundary condition to find $x_0(t)$ which makes $x_0(t) = \alpha e^{-t}$.

Should I then just replace all $x_0(t)$ by $\alpha e^{-t}$ and group by powers of $\alpha$? I find:
$
x_0'(t) + \alpha x_1'(t) + \dots =
-\alpha e^{-t} - \alpha x_1(t) - \alpha^2 x_2(t) - \dots
+ \alpha^{n+1} (e^{-t} + x_1(t) + \alpha x_2(t) + \dots)
+ \frac{\alpha^n n}{2}(1-\alpha e^{-t}-\alpha x_1(t)-\dots)(e^{-t}+ x_1(t)+\dots)^{n-1}
$

Comment: Now sice $x_0'(t) = -\alpha e^{-t}$ we may ignore this part and we get:
$\alpha x_1'(t) = -\alpha x_1(t)$ with boundary condition $x_1(t) = 0$. This makes $x_i(t) = 0$ for all $i < n$. From then on we get combinations of terms as you wrote in your answer.
Is this a good way to go about it?

Comment: @Darkwizie, if $x_0(0)= \alpha$, then yes, what you write for $x_1$ and other terms seems to be correct, because we need to keep exactly the terms proportional to $\alpha^k$ in the equation for each $x_k(t)$. Which makes the perturbation solution even more accurate. $$ $$ As for setting the initial condition for $x_0$ the same as for $x$, you have the right to do that (it's not necessary, but it seems to be the easiest way)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to continue this way :)! Fun way to solve an ODE!